# Best practice or pattern for DTO/Domain Objects

Tags: c#

I've a class below which is written to map with web service response message.

```
public class someclassA
{
   public int properyA {get;set;}
   public int properyB {get;set;}
   public int properyC {get;set;}
   public int properyD {get;set;}
}

public class someclassB
{
   public int properyX {get;set;}
   public int properyY {get;set;}
   public int properyZ {get;set;}
}
```

Now the requirement is that someClassA should use some properties from someClassB and add 3 more caculated properties e.g. propertyE, propertyF, propertyG etc.

The question regarding pattern is should I create completely different someClassAB to have all properties from someClassA and 3 new ones or should I just construct the someClassA with all those additinal field in the first place?

Cheers.

Comment: If all the properties in B also exist in A, this would probably be best handled by using inheritance.

Comment: Agree to lthibodeaux. Patterns must make our live easier. Yes DTO must be plain objects with simple properties, but it's best solution for you i think

Comment: Question updated, properties in classB are completely Alien to ClassA

Answer (score 2):

Here is the rule to keep in mind.  If A "is a" B, then use inheritance.  Otherwise, make them separate objects.  Inheritance should only be used in cases where the subclass is truly a more specific form of the parent class.

Think maintenance.  What happens when the objects start to diverge more and more in the future?  Now you have types being used where only say 20% of the properties make sense in a given context.

Not to mention, your code will be more readable if you have clear boundaries between unrelated entities.  Every time you throw inheritance into the picture, you have one more "context" you have to keep up with when reading the code.  If you mix objects (frankly out of laziness), the readability of the code suffers.

Comment: should there be another class that contains all the properties of ClassA and extra properties required by View then?

Comment: It depends on what your entities actually are.  You can go either way.  If B is a different type of A, then I would use inheritance.  If they have no relationship to each other, then create a separate object.  Don't use inheritance just to "borrow" properties.

Comment: Now if class B is a "view" of class A with some calculated fields, I'd be prone to put those as getter properties on class A (since a view is still of the same type).